# Get Content from file path

Tags: powershell, file-get-contents

I have a script that will email a notification when a file exists. It takes a line of text from the file and emails it to the recipient.

It works fine when the script is ran in the same folder in which the files are located in. However, if I put the script on my desktop and try to run it; the `Get-Content` is looking for the `$file` on my desktop - not the `R:\files\export` location.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -path "R:\Files\export" |
         where {($_.extension -eq '.old' -and $_ -like '*AM*')}

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $a = Get-Content $file | select -First 1 -Skip 9 
    $a = $a.substring(3,16)

    $emailMessage.Body = @"
The following Amazon PO has been imported to LM: </br></br>
"@ + $a
```

In the code above, how do I correctly specify the file path?

```
$a = Get-Content $file | select -first 1 -skip 9
```

Comment: A similar question has been asked and answered less than 12 hours ago. Please put some more effort in your research before asking a question here.

Comment: I spent more than enough time googling *Rolls eyes*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the property `fullname` to get the full path.

```
$a =  Get-Content $file.fullname | select -first 1 -skip 9
```